# Select connectionstring simultaneously

Tags: c#, asp.net

My website connection string is managed depends upon the dropdown selection.

In `web.config` I have:

```
<add name="DUM01" 
     connectionString="Data Source=CHETAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DUM01;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add name="DUM02" 
     connectionString="Data Source=CHETAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DUM02;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Class file:

```
public class ConnectionStr
{
    public int iClientId = 0;
    public string sCon = string.Empty;

    public string StrConnection(string strClientName)
    {
        if (strClientName != string.Empty)
        {
            if (strClientName == "")
            {
                sCon = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""]);
            }
            else if (strClientName == "DUM02")
            {  
               sCon = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DUM02"]);

            }
            else if (strClientName == "DUM01")
            {
                sCon = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DUM01"]);
            }
        }

        return sCon;
    }
}
```

Dropdown:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" 
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="tr">
     <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Simons Holidays" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="RVL Logistics" Value="DUM02"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Simon Shipping" Value="DUM01"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Dropdown SelectIndexChanged:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sClientName = Convert.ToString(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
    Session["ClientName"] = sClientName;

    ConnectionStr objConnectionStr = new ConnectionStr();
    string strConnection = objConnectionStr.StrConnection(sClientName);

    if (Session["ClientName"] != null)
    {
        sClientName = Convert.ToString(Session["ClientName"]);
    }

    strConnection = objConnectionStr.StrConnection(sClientName);

    SqlConnection scon1 = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
}
```

and when I need to use it any web form then I use:

```
public partial class Webforms_VendorsWithBoot : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string sClientName = string.Empty;
    public static string strConnection = string.Empty;
    public static DataTable TableData = new DataTable();
    public static string brcode = string.Empty;

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["ClientName"] != null)
        {
            sClientName = Convert.ToString(Session["ClientName"]);
        }

        ConnectionStr objConnectionStr = new ConnectionStr();
        strConnection = objConnectionStr.StrConnection(sClientName);
    }
}
```

Now the situation is when database is DUM01 is selected I need DUM02 is also available simultaneously and vise versa, because some table in both database are the same and in some webforms I need to insert data in both databases.

How to solve this? Thanks in advance..

Comment: use one master database where store ClientName and database name. and then based on client name create connection for database which configured with same client in master database. using this approch you need to only configure master database connection string in web.config file

Comment: any example....

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use **Database Replication** for this. you said you have same DB with Same tables in it. [Check this out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) . 
Replication helps you to manage your data from both Primary and Secondary DBs. you don't have to worry about which db you are using to insert data. this will be reflected automatically.

Answer (score 0):

[image: please check in image]

like this you can create database structure

Comment: Hi Hitesh i not understand exactly how it works give one example with my posted code..Now i create one database with same client name with different database name